# Java abstract class fields override

Tags: java, class, overriding, field, abstract

I have an abstract class that should implement a public field, this field is an interface or another abstract classe.

something like this:

```
public abstract class GenericContainer {
    public GenericChild child;
}

public abstract class GenericChild {
    public int prop1=1;
}

public abstract class SpecialChild extends GenericChild {
    public int prop1=2;
}
```

Now i have another specialized class Container:

```
public abstract class SpecialContainer extends GenericContainer {
    public SpecialChild child=new SpecialChild(); //PAY ATTENTION HERE!
}
```

Java allow me to compile this, and i IMAGINE that the field `child` in `SpecialContainer` is automatically overloading the field `child` of the `GenericContainer`...
The questions are:
Am i right on this? The automatic 'overloading' of child will happen?

And, more important question, if i have another class like this:

```
public class ExternalClass {
    public GenericContainer container=new SpecialContainer();
    public int test() {
         return container.child.prop1
    }
}
```

`test()` will return 1 or 2? i mean the `GenericContainer` container field what `prop1` will call, the generic or the special?
And what if the special prop1 was declared as String (yes java allow me to compile also in this case)?

Thanks!

Comment: No. fields don't get overridden, only methods do.

Comment: So if in 'SpecialChild' i have a method that use prop1, what it will get at the first call? 1 or 2?

I tried and removing prop1 from SpecialChild will allow me to write a method in SpecialChild that use prop1 also if this is only defined in GenericChild... So i think a kind of overload happens...

Comment: you could always try _running it_.

Comment: Above program throws "NullPointerException". For the question you asked, its answer is fields cannot be overriden. If you define same field name in the subclass then subclass field will hide super class's field.

Comment: @AmitG yes because in the GenericContainer i've not initialized Generic child. on my complete project it worked.

Comment: @Alex: In that case it is ok. You must be assigning that object. Hope you have got many answer..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It isn't overriding anything, you're just hiding the original field at the current class scope. If you use a variable with the subtype you will still be able to access the original property. Example:

```
abstract class GenericContainer {
    public GenericChild child;       
}

abstract class GenericChild {
    public int prop1=1 ;
}

class SpecialChild extends GenericChild {
    public int prop1=2;
}

class SpecialContainer extends GenericContainer {
    public SpecialChild child;
}

public class Main {

    public static void main( String ... args ) {

        GenericContainer container = new SpecialContainer();
        container.child = new SpecialChild();

        System.out.println( container.child.prop1 );

        SpecialChild child = (SpecialChild) container.child;        
        System.out.println( child.prop1 );
    }

}
```

This prints 1 and then 2.

From `SpecialChild` you would also be able to go up one level using `super`:

```
class SpecialChild extends GenericChild {
    public int prop1=2;

    public int getOriginalProp1() {
        return super.prop1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Spot on! 
Accessing the abstract super field from the specific child is the key concept behind this approach.

Answer (score 17):

In Java, data members/attributes are not polymorphic. Overloading means that a field will have a different value depending from which class it's accessed. The field in the subclass will **hide** the field in the super-class, but both exists. **The fields are invoked based  on reference types, while methods are used of actual object**. You can try it yourself.

It's called, variable hiding/shadowing, for more details look on [here](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-variable-hiding-and-shadowing/15)

Comment: Thanks but the link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding

> ....and i IMAGINE that the field "child" in SpecialContainer is automatically overloading the field 'child' of the GenericContainer...

No. Fields don't get overridden, only methods do.

This is one reason why use of (overridable) getter and setter methods are preferred to direct access to fields. Your fields should almost all be private.

As for your design, there's no need for your SpecialContainer class to have a SpecialChild field, but instead the SpecialChild object should be placed in the GenericChild field.

Answer (score 2):

**Why nobody is observing that program will throw `NullPointerException`.**

subclass's `field` with same name will hide super class's `field`. There is no `overriding` with `field`. Overriding is only possible with methods.

Original Code by Author:

```
public abstract class GenericContainer {
    public GenericChild child;
}

public abstract class GenericChild {
    public int prop1=1;
}

public abstract class SpecialChild extend GenericChild {
    public int prop1=2;
}

public abstract class SpecialContainer extends GenericContainer {
    public SpecialChild child=new SpecialChild(); //PAY ATTENTION HERE!
}

public class ExternalClass {
    public GenericContainer container=new SpecialContainer();
    public int test() {
         return container.child.prop1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Java allow me to compile this, and i IMAGINE that the field "child" in
>   SpecialContainer is automatically overloading the field 'child' of the
>   GenericContainer...

Firstly, **Inheritence** doesn't apply to variables. Fields(Insatnce variables) are not overridden in your sub-class.they are only visible in your subclass if they are marked with  either `public, protected or default`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question it maintains both instances.  And depending on how you refer to the container (either through the abstract or the impl) determines which variable you are referring to.

```
public class Test {

   public abstract class Container{
       public Generic gen = new Generic();
   }

   public class ContainerImpl extends Container{
       public GenericImpl gen = new GenericImpl();
   }

   public class Generic{
       public int prop = 0;
   }

   public class GenericImpl extends Generic{
       public int prop = 1;
   }

   public Test(){
       Container c = new ContainerImpl();
       System.out.println(c.gen.prop); // Outputs "0"
       System.out.println(((ContainerImpl)c).gen.prop); // Output "1"
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Test();
   }

}
```

The bigger question at hand is, why would you design something like this? I'm assuming you are asking from a theoretical perspective.

My 2 cents, this isn't great OO design.  You would be better off making the public variables private and assigning their values through a constructor or property setter.  As-is, it will lead to unexpected results in your code.