# Assinging object of inherited class to reference of super class

Tags: java

Given the follwoing Code:

```
public class A {
     int at=2;

    public int m(int i){return at+i;}
}

class B extends A {
     int at=3;

        public int m(int i){return at+5*i;}
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        A x = new B();

        System.out.println("Output "+x.m(x.at));
    }
}
```

The output is 13.

How does it work?
I know that it takes method from B, but what about arguments?

Comment: You're not assigning it to an *object*, you're assigning it to a *reference*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at expression: `x.m(x.at)`. Since `x` is cdeclared as `A`, `x.at` will refer to `at` field in `A`.

However, it gets more complicated when it comes to methods. Although `x` is declared as `A`, `x` in fact is of type `B`, so method `m` will be called from `x`'s acctual class, `B`.

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311757/java-abstract-class-fields-override) coud help.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you have two `at` fields one declared in `A` and other in `B`. Method `m` in `A` refers to field `at` in `A`; method `m` in `B` refers to filed `at` in `B`. Method is overridden, field is not. `x` is declared as instance of `A` so `x.at` is 2. When you call method `m` the overridden method is called (`B.m(2)`) so you get 3+5*2 = 13.

In such cases [Java Language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) should tell you what's right and why. Answer to this question can be found in [8.3. Field Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3)

> If the class declares a field with a certain name, then the
>   declaration of that field is said to hide any and all accessible
>   declarations of fields with the same name in superclasses, and
>   superinterfaces of the class.
>
> A hidden field can be accessed by using a qualified name (§6.5.6.2) if
>   it is static, or by using a field access expression that contains the
>   keyword super (§15.11.2) or a cast to a superclass type.

cast to a superclass type is your case.

Answer (score 1):

Variables does not override like methods. So variables value depends on Reference Variable not on  the instance being referenced by this reference variable.

example: in your case. In main() method

A x =new B();

reference variable x is of type A and it hold a reference of an instance of type B.

So as X is of type A. WhenEver you write x.at it being refer Class A variable.